i am trying to get daily consumption of smartmeter for a week on aws timestream
i am trying to get daily consumption from smartmeter table for each week  from aws timestream but its returning all the data thats the smartmeter has used    SELECT
date_trunc('week', CURRENT_DATE),
meter_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN measure_name = 'ActEnPosT1' THEN measure_value::varchar END) AS value_actenpost1_10m
FROM
"mykrogrid"."smart_meter1.0"
WHERE
time BETWEEN ago(24h) AND NOW()
AND measure_name = 'ActEnPosT1'
GROUP BY
date_trunc('day', time),
meter_id`;
SELECT
date_trunc('week', CURRENT_DATE),
meter_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN measure_name = 'ActEnPosT1' THEN measure_value::varchar END) AS value_actenpost1_10m
FROM
"mykrogrid"."smart_meter1.0"
WHERE
time BETWEEN ago(24h) AND NOW()
AND measure_name = 'ActEnPosT1'
GROUP BY
date_trunc('day', time),
meter_id`;

Just ran a similar test. The underlying data is in UTC, so when you try to filter with WHERE time BETWEEN ago(24h) and now() the data likely spans 2 days (over midnight), so with GROUP BY date_trunc('day', time), meter_id you might get 2 records for each meter_id
